# What command I should write on a console to detect master ip of Redis that is installed on my Ubuntu 14.04 machine?

Tags: ubuntu, redis, redis-server

On my Ubuntu 14.04 where I installed Redis.

I want to configure Master-Slave replication. To do this, in `redis.conf` file, I should put this command =>

```
slaveof <masterip> <masterport>
```

But, how I can detect what is my master ip and and master password?

Answer (score 1):

If the master and slave are on same machine. You can use localhost in .

If Master and Slave are on different machines, get the IP of machine where master of redis setup is running by executing :
`ifconfig` command in terminal.

Master password is from your redis.conf of master redis serverusing (if you setup).
Check
`requirepass` in redis.conf.